# Save the views added dynamically

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I want to save the views added dynamically in my layout. So, when I come back to my activity, I want to find my added views. This is the code that I add views

Code:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
    if (check == true) {
        SanksionLabel = (ViolationDTO) SpinnerSanksioni.getSelectedItem();
        Log.d("Yes", SanksionLabel.toString());
        final LinearLayout rootLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.layout_shkelja);
        if (!sanksionetArray.contains(SanksionLabel)) {
            LinearLayout linearLayout1 = new LinearLayout(getActivity().getBaseContext());
            linearLayout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            TextView sanksionivalue = new TextView(getActivity().getBaseContext());
            sanksionetArray.add(SanksionLabel);
            sanksionivalue.setText(counttextview + ". " + SanksionLabel);
            sanksionivalue.setTag(counttextview + "txtview");
            sanksionivalue.setTextColor(R.color.Black);
            sanksionivalue.setTextSize(20);
            sanksionivalue.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramssanksioni = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(600, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            paramssanksioni.setMargins(0, 8, 0, 0);
            sanksionivalue.setLayoutParams(paramssanksioni);
            linearLayout1.addView(sanksionivalue, 0);
            btnfshishkeljen = new ImageView(getActivity().getBaseContext());
            btnfshishkeljen.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_delete_textview_24dp);
            btnfshishkeljen.setTag("tag" + count);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(60, 60);
            btnfshishkeljen.setLayoutParams(params);
            linearLayout1.addView(btnfshishkeljen, 1);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            layoutParams.setMargins(40, 20, 30, 0);
            linearLayout1.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.textview_underline));
            linearLayout1.setTag("tag" + count + "linear");
            rootLayout.addView(linearLayout1, 2, layoutParams);
            count++;
            counttextview++;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean of saving views ? you mean to save state of views ?

Answer (score 0):

When the Activity is stopped, for example when you switch to another application, the activity will be restarted when you return to your activity. In this case, you will loose for example the layouts you have added while runtime.

What you could do is override the function `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` where you have the chance to save the current state of your activity before it will be stopped. When returning back to your activity,  the function `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` will be called where you have the chance to restore the views to the state before it was stopped.

For detailed information, please see the article https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#java.

Comment: But I don't think that exist any way that you can save the layout in bundle. Please if you can help me

Comment: You can just save all the data needed to recreate the layout when recreating the activity.

Comment: Exactly, you have to store all information you have about content or location of these layouts using primitive types